# Protractor - inject JavaScript into tested page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, protractor

I am writing an auto-login script for Chrome Extension, I would like to use Protractor to be able to run multiple test against different web pages.

Chrome Extension is adding JavaScript code into the webpage/tab.

Can use Protractor to do the same? i.e. Create a script tag inside tested page & run the code?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use executeScript or executeAsyncScript:

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeAsyncScript

Those functions come from the webdriver api itself. To access them just use:

```
browser.executeScript('js code to run on the browser')
```

or

```
browser.executeAsyncScript(function fnToRunInBrowser(inputFromTest) {}, inputForSript).then(...)
```